# Changing stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a proc that print checks if there is any new checks to be print. If there is nothing  to issue new checks it wont print any. Now i want to modify this proc like even if i don't have any new checks to be print, it should pick up at least one check to be print.( even if it is already printed). Can you tell me how to do that. Here is the stored proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [proc_1250_SELCashiersChecksForPrint] AS

SELECT t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Audit_DateAdded, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.BatchNbr, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.SerialNbr, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.CheckRTN, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.CheckAccountNbr, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Amount, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.DateIssued, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Payee, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Address, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.City, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.State, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Zip, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimId, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.NoticeDate, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.FirstName, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.MiddleName, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.LastName, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimTotal, 
    t_PCD_Claimant.Name AS Agency, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.IDENTITYCOL
FROM t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued INNER JOIN
    t_DATA_Reclamation ON 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr = t_DATA_Reclamation.ControlNbr
     INNER JOIN
    t_PCD_Claimant ON 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimantCode = t_PCD_Claimant.ClaimantCode
WHERE (t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.SerialNbr IS NULL) AND 
    (t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.DateIssued IS NULL)
ORDER BY t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Audit_DateAdded ASC, 
         t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr ASC
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Why would you want to print a cheque if it has already been printed?  In my experience, nothing undermines a user's trust in an IT system than it doing something inexplicable like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT TOP 1  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr,
              t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Audit_DateAdded,
              t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.BatchNbr,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.SerialNbr,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.CheckRTN,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.CheckAccountNbr,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Amount,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.DateIssued,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Payee,                                              t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Address,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.City, t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.State,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Zip, t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimId,
                  t_DATA_Reclamation.NoticeDate, t_DATA_Reclamation.FirstName,
                  t_DATA_Reclamation.MiddleName, t_DATA_Reclamation.LastName,
                  t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimTotal, t_PCD_Claimant.Name AS Agency,
                  t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.IDENTITYCOL
      FROM    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued
      INNER JOIN t_DATA_Reclamation ON t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr = t_DATA_Reclamation.ControlNbr
      INNER JOIN t_PCD_Claimant ON t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimantCode = t_PCD_Claimant.ClaimantCode
    ORDER BY t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Audit_DateAdded DESC

Answer (score 0):

Use the **TOP n** SQL syntax :

```
if EXISTS ( /* Look for an unprinted check - "date_issued is null" */ )
   /* print unprinted checks */
ELSE
   select top 1 /* already-printed-checks  */
   where .... "date_issued is not null"
```

OR

Do you want to print a "Voided/Cancelled" check - when you do that?

Comment: instead of changing the  vb code can we change the stored proc?

Comment: "top 1" does not exist in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide how you want to pick your "at least one".

The simplest way (probably) is to remove whatever condition in the `WHERE` clause is excluding already printed checks. Let's assume that's `t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.DateIssued IS NULL`. Now add a column to your `SELECT` clause like this: `CASE WHEN t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.DateIssued IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END`  and make that column first in your ORDER BY clause.

Now in the procedure, fetch just one row from this cursor. If this new column has the value 0, there's at least one new check to be processed and you should iterate through the cursor but stop when you get to an already issued one. If it has the value 1, there are no new checks.

Edit: The other approach would be to do it right in your SQL. Leave the original as is, but add a clause like:
`UNION ALL SELECT ... AND ROWNUM = 1` where ... represents your existing query, but with the condition to exclude already printed checks removed. On second thought, this may be simpler.